# What is the name of "More results from ____" in google SERP and how to get it on your site?

Tags: seo, google-search

What is the name of this section of Google search?
[image]

It's not sitelinks - those are different sections of the website.

Is this in any way linked to Q&A html microdata Google uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are a type of Google Rich Results specficially for Q&A. In order to be considered for those type of search results, you'll need to use the Q&A structured data markup.

Google provides detailed information about what it is, how to implement it and examples [Here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage) and [Here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/12/rich-results-expands-for-question.html)

Comment: Why do Google Rich Results for Q&A look different in documentation? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/images/qa-example-screenshot.png

Comment: It depends on device. Just from what I've noticed I tend to see the more bubble looking results as you have posted in the image above on mobile but when on desktop the same search would show more like the images in your question or even the newer style with the drop down menu for each question.